# Why does this CSS transition event not fire when two classes are added?

Tags: css-transitions, dom-events

CSS

```
.horizontalTranslate {
    -webkit-transition: 3s;
}
.secondClass {
    background: red;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class='box'></div>
```

JS

```
var box = document.querySelector('.box');

box.addEventListener('webkitTransitionEnd', function(evt) {
    alert('Finished transition!');
}, false);

function transitionBox() {
    // this works
    box.className = 'horizontalTranslate';

    // this does not work
    // box.className = 'secondClass horizontalTranslate'; 
}
setTimeout(transitionBox, 100);
```

Why does the transition event not fire when two classes are added rather than one? I've also tried chaining my CSS selector, a la `.secondClass.horizontalTranslate { ... }`.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that `box.className = 'horizontalTranslate';` is actually removing styling, causing the CSS transition to actually happen. But when I set `box.className = 'secondClass horizontalTranslate';`, the styling of the DOM node is not changing and no event is fired.

Another way to write `transitionBox` is this:

```
function transitionBox() {
    box.classList.add('horizontalTranslate');
    box.classList.add('blue');
}
```

If `blue` changes the styling of `box`, this works too.