# CSS transition not working when two classes are added

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-transitions

Before I say anything, I looked at about a dozen SO threads including this one which you'll see the code suggested in there in my JSBin as well: [Why does this CSS transition event not fire when two classes are added?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24513581/why-does-this-css-transition-event-not-fire-when-two-classes-are-added)

The issue is that adding two classes back to back too fast results in no transition animation whatsoever.

I'm implementing this into a legacy JS custom right click menu and making it mobile friendly with just CSS by first applying the mobile styles with `.mobile-menu` then an animation class of `.mobile-menu-show` when they long press (since there's no right click mouse button).

The transitions don't work this way though. If I add `.mobile-menu` on page load it's fine, but I can't because I'm adding the `mobile-menu` class based on *how* the right click menu is triggered (long press == mobile styles, right click == normal styles)

Demo code: http://jsbin.com/maxuku/edit?html,css,output

==Edit==

Hopefully to clarify, I want the menu you see at the default to go hidden (`translateY(100%)`) then slide up from the bottom. If you use Slack, long press on a message. Or iPhone's had this same concept here where it would slide up:

[image]

Comment: Your classes mobile-menu and mobile-menu-show have opposite translates (100%) and (0%). Set the item at the start translate value and have the added class change it. That way you aren't adding two classes that cancel each other out.

Comment: I am still trying to figure out what you are looking for.. Do you mean like this? http://jsbin.com/nuvisofopi/1/edit?html,css,output  The transitions are there, but the functionality still doesn't make sense to me..

Comment: @mhodges i updated my original post. It's basically the opposite of what you have in the JSBin. When you click the button the content you see visible (it's hidden in the real app) would be hidden with `translateY(100%)` then animate up from the bottom with `translateY(0%)`. The end result, before sliding back down out of the screen, would be http://take.ms/WEFBK

Answer (score 3, accepted):

please change css class as below

```
.context-menu {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: -100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 100;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.25s; /* Safari */
  transition: all 0.25s;
}

.mobile-menu {
  background: #fff;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}

.mobile-menu-show {
  bottom: 0;
}
```

You can refer to animation over here
https://plnkr.co/edit/t0EB5CiuwtbWHqWXvlvz?p=preview

Comment: `translateY(100%)` would hide the menu, not show it though (afaik). 0% would put it where I want it (`bottom:0; left:0`). So this example starts correctly but when it runs it animates outside of the screen

Comment: ok i am little confused. are you looking for something like this https://plnkr.co/edit/t0EB5CiuwtbWHqWXvlvz?p=preview

Comment: Yes! that's the animation im looking for!

Comment: great than i will update my answer. sorry for earlier confusion